# How to run a Python script with 3rd party packages in Xcode Build Phase

Tags: python, ios, xcode

On my mac, Python3 is installed at **/usr/local/bin/python3**.

When I run *which python3* in Xcode Build Phase run script, it shows **/applications/xcode.app/contents/developer/usr/bin/python3**.

Apparently, there's another python embedded in Xcode or MacOS. Since I've imported some 3rd party packages in my Python script and this embedded one doesn't know how to find them, it gives me errors like **No module named 'XXX'**.

One possible solution is that I can specify the absolute Python3 path like: **/usr/local/bin/python3 my_script.py**. However, Python installation path is different for each guy in my team and I should not hardcode it.

Is there any elegant way to solve this issue?

Comment: Read about [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). It is the elegant solution you are looking for.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I followed this doc and use python3 -m venv --copies My_Env to create a virtual env. However, when it is running on another Mac that does not install Python3, it shows me errors. Do I miss something?